# MySQL - Is there a way to match a table data to a given string rather than vice versa

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM disney;
+++++++NAME+++++++
lion king
cinderella
the little mermaid
+++++++++++++++++++

$string = "i love the movie lion king, it rocks!"
```

I want to get the NAME from disney where the NAME is inside the given string. It's kinda like:

```
'SELECT * FROM disney WHERE NAME LIKE "%'.$string.'%";'
```

only the other way around (but didn't work well when i tried it).

Is there a MYSQL function to check whether a data in a table cell exists in a given string?

Thanks a lot! ().i'm working with **PHP**!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM disney WHERE NAME LIKE '%{$string}%';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work (I remember trying to do the same once, and I think this is what I used) :

```
'SELECT * FROM disney WHERE "' . $string . '" LIKE CONCAT("%",NAME,"%")';
```

Comment: That will only put a wildcard on the righthand side of the query.

Comment: OMG Ponies, I've changed it to suit my needs (concat(%,name,%))

Answer (score 1):

There's the [INSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) Function which should work for this:

```
SELECT * FROM disney WHERE INSTR('i love the movie lion king, it rocks!', name) > 0
```

Comment: Change the double quotes to single quotes, and that will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try MySQL's [FULLTEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) search feature which only works with MyISAM tables:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM disney WHERE MATCH(NAME) AGAINST ('$text')";
```